# kvm uefi boot into UEFI shell

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I use kvm and qemu and ovmf to set up a vm.
while I config it to boot on UEFI,it runs into UEFI shell.

[image]
My VM xml is following:

```
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>win7-2</name>
  <uuid>5efd80f4-498c-4e07-b607-bc6b0b360142</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/7"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-5.2">hvm</type>
    <loader readonly="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win7-2_VARS.fd</nvram>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state="off"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-model" check="partial"/>
  <clock offset="localtime">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
    <timer name="hypervclock" present="yes"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/home/bbyqqe/Documents/win7-2.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="sda" bus="sata"/>
      <boot order="2"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/home/bbyqqe/Documents/cn_windows_7_enterprise_with_sp1_x64_dvd_u_677685.iso"/>
      <target dev="sdb" bus="sata"/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order="1"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/home/bbyqqe/Documents/virtio-win-0.1.217.iso"/>
      <target dev="sdc" bus="sata"/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1d" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1">
      <master startport="0"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1d" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2">
      <master startport="2"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1d" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3">
      <master startport="4"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1d" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="sata" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root"/>
    <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="bridge">
      <mac address="52:54:00:18:58:a5"/>
      <source bridge="br0"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="spicevmc">
      <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </input>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="spice" autoport="yes">
      <listen type="address"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model="ich9">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1b" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

I set ovmf as

I have OVMF installed on

```
/usr/share/OVMF
```

while the guide shows

```
/usr/share/ovmf/x64
```

I didn't whether it concerns.
I also have /usr/share/ovmf but there is other file in it.
And I set `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` 
as

```
nvram = [
"/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd:/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd",
"/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.ms.fd:/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.ms.fd",
"/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.fd:/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.fd",
"/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.ms.fd:/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd",
]
```

because I have no bin but fd file.

[image]

My system is debian 11 amd64 installed on 5700G on msi B550 which is booted on UEFI.
I can set up win7 VM normally on BIOS boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Ubuntu 22 and to run with TPM and secureboot, setting firmware to `UEFI x86_64: /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.ms.fd` and adding a TPM device worked for me. This then allows the OS to boot via installation media and also detect secure boot capability. Tested with Windows 11 as well, but need to be quick pressing any key on `Press any key to boot from CD or DVD...` otherwise, you will drop into the UEFI Boot manager promtpt, from which you can type `exit` and press Enter. You will then be able to choose `Boot Manager` then select the `DVD-ROM` option to boot into Windows installation.

[image: QEMU/KVM config for UEFI boot]

[image: QEMU/KVM running Ubuntu 22 with UEFI and TPM Secureboot]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]